# ASP.net MVC: why is AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() so slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

I have a small ASP.net MVC application with approximately 10 Views and 2 Controllers, which takes forever (not forever but between 30-50 seconds) to load a site.

I did some profiling and found out that over 50% of the time was spend on the following line in my Global.asax.cs file:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

What could be the reason and how can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using MVC Areas? If not, simply remove or comment that line out. I've noticed this before but have no real explanation for it.

Comment: its added by default when an MVC project is created. I've removed it without issues in my applications when I'm not using areas. If you were to use areas, you'd obviously need to turn it back on.

Comment: that i know its added by default and it's significance. Lets see what effects does Preli see after removing this

Comment: I removed the line. It still works. It is still slow! Seems like the profiler is showing me wrong information. It seems not to show what is really slowing down everything. In addition I now have the problem that it is reasonably fast on my pc, but very slow on the production system (although the production server has much more power than my notebook).

Comment: Is it only slow on the initial hit of the site? This could be caused by the application pool warmup. Once the application has been hit once, does it continue to be fast? You could look into a keep alive service for your site once you go live into production. There are no real good ways around this for .net applications unfortunately. Microsoft added a feature in .NET 4 that allows you to do some sort of settings on the application pool to keep it from shutting down as well, I just cannot think of what they called it at this time, I'll search around and see if I can figure it out for you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is always slow not just on the first hit. I am quite sure the problem is in my code somewhere - maybe I should try a different profiler.

Comment: Yea, I would assume it's somewhere else if it's slow all the time. The AreaRegistration is ONLY going to fire on Application_Start, so it should not affect any other requests except the initial to the site. Good luck in your endeavor

Comment: Doesn't answer the question "why is [...] so slow?"

Answer (score 1):

It is slow because it will reflect all assemblies looking for area registrations and build a cache file. See also [Inside Areas Registration](https://lukasz-lysik.github.io/asp.net/2013/08/17/inside-areas-registration-how-does-registerallareas-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4.html).

If you're using areas, I've written a small extension to register specific areas, so you don't take the hit of needing to scan all assemblies:

```cs
public static class AreaRegistrationExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register specific Area.
    ///
    /// This circumvents the slow RegisterAllAreas that will perform assembly scanning.
    /// Implementation based on MVC source code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TArea"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="application"></param>
    public static void RegisterArea<TArea>(this HttpApplication application) where TArea : AreaRegistration
    {
        var registration = (AreaRegistration)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TArea));
        var context = new AreaRegistrationContext(registration.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        string str = typeof(TArea).Namespace;
        if (str != null)
            context.Namespaces.Add(str + ".*");
        registration.RegisterArea(context);
    }
}
```

Usage in `Application_Start`:

```cs
this.RegisterArea<MyArea>();
```